# How to synchronize files state in PHPStorm ( IDEA ) from filewatcher script

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm, filesystemwatcher, file-watcher

I create file watcher script for converting *.ts into *.js ( that's dose n't matter ) - it works perfectly, but Storm update output file state not in realtime. I should to wait or run Synchronize command from context menu.

Is there any way to do this operation from script?

Thx a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems the Storm can't match the specified output path with actual output. If the pattern specified in `Output paths to refresh` field doesn't match the transpiler output, virtual file system is not updated and the file state in IDE doesn't match its state on disk. Please attach a screenshot of your file watcher settings

Comment: Thx. I didn't pay attention. The only question - how to create complicated transformation for output path? Not from one folder to another< but several transformations

Comment: not sure i follow you... Why do you need several transformations for a single watcher?

Comment: current project structure - we didn't start from scratch. I just review ability of migration to typescript ( Of course we can use symlinks and others ) -

Comment: again don't understand. You can't pass several different --outDir options to typescript compiler - just one. so the generated files will always be put in certain directory. Just make sure that the pattern in 'output  paths to refresh' matches the path you specify in --outDir parameter. If it's still not clear, please let me know what you are trying to do exactly